# How can I get the classes applied via HTML on an Angular 2 component?

Tags: angular

I want to use a component that I've created as follows:

```
<vx-alert class="au-upper-center">
    <p>Upper Center</p>
</vx-alert>
```

Within the `vx-alert` component I want to pull the list of classes that were applied in the HTML that caused the component to be instantiated. Ultimately I want to either append additional classes to the `vx-alert` component. I am able to replace the `vx-alert` component classes very easily (as follows):

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'vx-alert',
    templateUrl: 'alert.html'
})
export class AlertComponent extends I18N implements OnInit {
    @HostBinding('class') private classList:string;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.classList = 'au-ease-in-out au-20000ms';
   }
}
```

but when `this.classList` is assigned as new value, the original class(es) set within the HTML code are overwritten... so how can I retrieve the HTML provided classes so that I can concatenate these to my programmatically determined classes?

My Plunker has been updated to use the answer provided by @acdcjunior:

http://embed.plnkr.co/AKYU9ANRm5ogzhlzY9G0/

Comment: Can't see the question clearly. Can you put a plnkr.co

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider the `class` attribute of `vx-alert` an input to it (`@Input('class')`). That way, you can read its value.

After that, you can use `@HostBinding('class')` to amend it:

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'vx-alert',
    templateUrl: 'alert.html'
})
export class AlertComponent extends I18N implements OnInit {
  @Input('class') initialClassList: string;
  @HostBinding('class') private classList:string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.classList = this.initialClassList + ' au-ease-in-out au-20000ms';
  }
}
```

See [demo plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/lQ7WkWy5PolCcKFUcm3A?p=preview).